# Is SharePoint's ListViewXML syntax based on a standard?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, listview

I had to change a ListView webpart and noticed the syntax that renders the HTML is not XSLT. Is this ListViewXML syntax documented somewhere or based on a standard?

Example,

```
<IfEqual>
            <Expr1>
                <GetVar Name="BlogPublishedCurrentDate"/>
            </Expr1>
            <Expr2>
                <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
            </Expr2>
            <Then/>
            <Else>
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[<h3 class="ms-PostDate">]]></HTML>
                <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[</h3>]]></HTML>
                <SetVar Name="BlogPublishedCurrentDate" Scope="Request">
                    <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
                </SetVar>
            </Else>
        </IfEqual>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specialized XML variant language for SharePoint called [CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588092(office.11).aspx)

It can be used for many different purposes within SharePoint, like creating queries on list, in list schema to define views etc.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439798%28v=office.12%29.aspx